# STLLoader on Three.js : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render some STL 3d models on three.js
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - STL</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="info">
            <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> -
            STL loader test by <a href="https://github.com/aleeper" target="_blank" rel="noopener">aleeper</a>.<br/>
            PR2 head from <a href="http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_description">www.ros.org</a>
        </div>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

            import { STLLoader } from './jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js';

            var container;

            var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 15 );
                camera.position.set( 3, 0.15, 3 );

                cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 0.25, 0 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x72645b );
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x72645b, 2, 15 );


                // Ground

                var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 40, 40 ),
                    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, specular: 0x101010 } )
                );
                plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                plane.position.y = - 0.5;
                scene.add( plane );

                plane.receiveShadow = true;


                // ASCII file

                var loader = new STLLoader();
                loader.load( 'My_model.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    mesh.position.set( 0, - 0.25, 0.6 );
                    mesh.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 2, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );

                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                } );


                // Binary files

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );

                loader.load( 'My_model.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    mesh.position.set( 0, - 0.37, - 0.6 );
                    mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );

                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                } );

                loader.load( 'My_model.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    mesh.position.set( 0.136, - 0.37, - 0.6 );
                    mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, 0.3, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );

                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                } );

                // Colored binary STL
                loader.load( 'My_model.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var meshMaterial = material;
                    if ( geometry.hasColors ) {

                        meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { opacity: geometry.alpha, vertexColors: true } );

                    }

                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, meshMaterial );

                    mesh.position.set( 0.5, 0.2, 0 );
                    mesh.rotation.set( - Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 0.3, 0.3, 0.3 );

                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                } );


                // Lights

                scene.add( new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0x443333, 0x111122 ) );

                addShadowedLight( 1, 1, 1, 0xffffff, 1.35 );
                addShadowedLight( 0.5, 1, - 1, 0xffaa00, 1 );
                // renderer

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function addShadowedLight( x, y, z, color, intensity ) {

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( color, intensity );
                directionalLight.position.set( x, y, z );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                directionalLight.castShadow = true;

                var d = 1;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;

                directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
                directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 4;

                directionalLight.shadow.bias = - 0.002;

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
            

            }

            function render() {

                var timer = Date.now() * 0.0005;

                camera.position.x = Math.cos( timer ) * 3;
                camera.position.z = Math.sin( timer ) * 3;

                camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code is basically a slightly modified version of the STLLoader code example.

However, i get this error:

```
  STLLoader:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have the STL file in the same directory with the HTML file. All the other js libs are in the correct file structure.

What am i missing here?

Comment: In the browser's dev tools, open the Network tab. Look at the entry that is actually throwing the 404. From there, you can see the full URL of the request. Take that URL and put it in your browser's address bar. If you get another 404, then the URL is wrong, and you need to figure out why. If the file downloads, then something else is wrong, and we'll probably need more information.

Comment: Yeah, that means the object to load is not at `My_model.stl`. Maybe you need to add the folder structure.